# Enabling / Disabling title from link on resizing of window browser

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link like this:

```
<a id="mylink" href="something" title="something">something</a>
```

Using jQuery how can I remove the `title` attribute depending on the site width?

```
if (Window.width > 460) {
   // disable title of mylink
}
```

In other words, when screen > 460px then the `title` of link need not to be displayed and when <= 460px then `title` of the link needs to be displayed.
Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you feel the need to do this? I would assume you're expecting this to work with a library, but it's very unlikely removing an attribute after instantiating the library will have any effect, as they are only read on load.

Comment: sure, i have a menu. when screen is < 460 i display this menu as a list of chapter. When it > 460 then i display too full text of it and so the title not need.
It need when i display it without full text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the title reference inside a data attribute and then when the document is loaded and when the windows is resized check the size of the window and set title attribute or remove it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setLinkTitle();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    setLinkTitle();
  })
})

function setLinkTitle(){
  if($(window).width() <= 460){
    $(".mylink").removeAttr("title");
  }
  else{
    $(".mylink").each(function(){
       $(this).attr("title",$(this).data("title"))
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="mylink" title="something" data-title="something">something</a>
```

Comment: It work, but not understand why don't work if <a></a> is putted inside a <div>…<li>….<a class="mylink"></a> </li></div> Need change code?